# Why can't Bran father a child?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the GoT finale, Sansa said that Bran couldn't father a child. And then, this fact was used by Tyrion Lannister to persuade Grey Worm that

> this is what the dead Daenerys meant by breaking the wheel.

My question is: How could anyone know that Bran was infertile? Nobody had access to advanced technology to determine that and Westeros would definitely have seen crippled people fathering child.

Comment: Because he lost the use of his lower body and can't feel anything below the waist. For most people, that's where the genitals are.

Comment: @Aegon Stephen Hawking couldn't feel the entire body and yet he had no trouble fathering a child with conventional way.

Comment: Hawking's disability was different and he was slowly paralysed over the course of his adulthood. Bran was throne from a tower and instantly paralysed before he became an adult or found a partner.

Comment: @Aegon - Game of Thrown?

Comment: Lol. Damn typo.

Comment: @Aegon The is no reason for paralysis to magically disable your genital. Sex is still [very possible](https://www.christopherreeve.org/living-with-paralysis/health/sexual-health/sexual-health-for-men) for paralyzed people.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat [Had that discussion in an older answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/134306/54887). Can he sire Children despite his disability? Maybe. Do characters in universe think that's unlikely? Yes.

Comment: @Aegon - Not least because people would assume that any kids he had were the result of cuckoldry.